# inner products on polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, measure-theory, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

So, I was studying about orthogonal polynomials and saw general examples of inner products on $\mathbb{R}[x]$, mostly of the forms
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int f(x)g(x)q(x)dx,$$
for some kind of density $q$; and an inner product of the form
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)g(x_k),$$
for some fixed set of $x_1,...,x_n$ (mostly the eigenvalues of some matrix). As it happens, in both cases we have that the product is of the form
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int fgd\mu,$$
for some measure $\mu$ defined on the borelians (the first case the absolut continuous $d\mu =qdm$ and the second the dirac measure supported on $x_j$)

My intuition is that for all cases there should be some measure, which we can define from the inner product. This intuition comes from Riez-Markov theorem, but there is no topological structure to be used here, so I cannot use it.

so the question is:

Is it true that every positive semi-definide inner product on $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is of the kind
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int fgd\mu,$$
for some measure $\mu$ that can be determined by the inner product?

If not I would really apreciate a counterexample, as I am new to this area...

Comment: Nice question.  But if you do not include your own efforts, it is likely to be closed.

Comment: @A Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your question to include where you came across this problem, what you have tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts you have.

Comment: Look up the Hamburger moment problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You'll need some additional hypotheses to make this work; in particular you haven't required your inner product to be compatible with the multiplicative structure of $\mathbb{R}[x]$.  Consider the inner product defined by forcing monomials to be orthonormal: $$\langle \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^n, \sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^n\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_k.$$ This is a positive-definite inner product on $\mathbb{R}[x]$.  If we have $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ in the form

$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int fg d\mu$$

then we have

$$0 = \langle 1, x^2\rangle = \int x^2 d\mu = \langle x, x \rangle = 1.$$

Perhaps if you also require a hypothesis such as $$\langle fg,h \rangle = \langle g, fh\rangle$$ then you can get some representation theorem.

Comment: Right (+). It suffices to add the assumption $\langle xp,q\rangle =\langle p,xq\rangle$ which amounts to the  multiplication by $x$ being symmetric.

Comment: or, in other terminology, self-adjoint.